# How to calculate runway length required for an A380 to takeoff?

Tags: takeoff, airbus-a380

I was wondering, how much runway length does an Airbus A380 require to takeoff? I saw other answers on Aviation S.E. but I didn't find how to calculate it to (I am curious to know how to calculate it). Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45185/21091) your question?

Comment: For any aircraft, calculating the TODR (take-off distance required), requires the pressure height of the aerodrome, shade temperature, runway surface, wind, wind direction, aircraft weight.